# Running Jenkins job with docker command on kubernetes cluster fails "docker: not found"

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jnlp

We are running a Kubernetes cluster for building Jenkins jobs. For the pods we are using the **odavid/jenkins-jnlp-slave** JNLP docker image. I mounted the /var/run/docker.sock to the pod container and added jenkins(uid=1000) user to the docker group on the host systems.

When running a shell script job in Jenkins with e.g. `docker ps` it fails with error `docker: not found`.

```
$ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6501091583256440803.sh
+ id
uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins)
+ docker ps
/tmp/jenkins2079497433467634278.sh: 8: /tmp/jenkins2079497433467634278.sh: docker: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The interesting thing is that when connecting into the pod manually and executing docker commands directly in the container as jenkins user, it works:

```
kubectl exec -it jenkins-worker-XXX -- /bin/bash
~$ su - jenkins
~$ id   
uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins),1000(jenkins)
~$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE        COMMAND         CREATED         STATUS
```

What is doing Jenkins in its job differently? Same user, same container, only `groups=1000(jenkins),1000(jenkins)` lists 1000(jenkins) as group 2 times when connecting manually. What am i missing?

Comment: is docker part of your path or provided with a fully qualified path in your script?

Comment: docker binary is part of the jnlp pod container https://hub.docker.com/r/odavid/jenkins-jnlp-slave/
The docker socket is mounted from the hostsystem.

Comment: What I mean is: What is the PATH env is the `/tmp/jenkins6501091583256440803.sh` script getting? if it does not get the PATH to docker than it should be provided with a fully qualified path in the script.... Try adjusting the shell script with a full path to the docker bin and see what happends

Comment: Good hint. I checked the path variable and it was correct but docker was not there. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/var/run/docker.sock is just the host socket that allows docker client to  run  docker commands from the container.

**What you are missing is the docker client in your container.**

Download the docker client manually and place it on a persistent volume and ensure that he docker client is in the system path. Also, ensure that the docker client is executable.

This command will do it  for you.  You may have to get the right version of the docker client for your environment

```
curl -fsSLO https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-17.03.1-ce.tgz &&
tar --strip-components=1 -xvzf docker-17.03.1-ce.tgz -C /usr/local/bin
```

You may even be able to install the  docker using the  package manager for your image.

Comment: Your are right! The pod image contains the docker client but the container doing the actual execution is missing the docker binary. I have overseen this. Thank you very much for your help!